# How to format date without year using Simple Date Format?

Tags: java

There is the following code:

```
public static String getDateOnCurrentTimezone(String date, String timezone) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd kk:mm:ss"); 
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(date);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code must format date from one timezone to other one without date, but it returns "null" always. If I change format to "yyyy-MM-dd" it works good. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: This code only returns null if an exception is thrown. What is the exception telling you?

Comment: "Unparseable date: "2013-09-05 19:48:05" (at offset 4)"

Comment: how you call this method with date string.? The date string value should be same as your pattern within SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the date and return a String with a different representation, you need two DateFormats:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(date);
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd kk:mm:ss").format(d);
```

Note that you probably meant to use `HH` instead of `kk`. Check the javadoc to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your params, you try to parse the date:

```
2013-09-05 19:48:05
```

With the format

```
MM-dd kk:mm:ss
```

This have two problems:

1. The hour, k is for 1-24, you probably want to use HH (0-23), see [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
2. Is not the same format, the format you pass is: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Try this code:

```
public static String getDateOnCurrentTimezone(String date, String timezone) {

    SimpleDateFormat outPutParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat inputPutParser = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    outPutParser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
    try {

        Date d = inputPutParser.parse(date);
        outPutParser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return outPutParser.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english