# How to get only the Date Month and time from a String

Tags: java

I get the following string from Database "2015-03-17 15:27:38"

From this i want to show only

```
03-17 15:27  (Month - Date and Time with minutes and seconds)
```

I was trying the following way

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
        String created = "2015-03-17 15:27:38";
        if (created != null && !created.isEmpty() && created.length() >= 19) {
            created = created.substring(0, created.length() - 5);
        }
        System.out.println(created);
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ?

Comment: Convert it to a `Date` and use a `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse (String)` to get a Date, then use Calendar to extract the fields

Comment: [how-to-format-date-without-year-using-simple-date-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672640/how-to-format-date-without-year-using-simple-date-format)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the `String` value to a `Date`, then use another `SimpleDateFormat` to format the value the way you wan it

```
try {
    String created = "2015-03-17 15:27:38";
    SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = in.parse(created);

    SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm");
    System.out.println(out.format(date));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication979.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Outputs `03-17 15:27`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can guarantee that the format of your date will never change, you should not start to create your own string parsing code.

Java offers you various "built-in" APIs to deal with numbers and dates; for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/